# Skrollr Animations choppy in IE 8 and IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The animations on a page I built that uses Skrollr are very choppy when scrolling the page in IE 8 and 9. I've tested some other sites from the examples section on https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr in IE 8 and 9 and did not notice any choppiness on the animations. Any thoughts on why this is occurring on my site? http://group.com/womens-ministry/where-moms-connect

Comment: First off, pretty cool site. It was slightly choppy on my machine of average hardware in IE9, but not unusable. One reason for choppiness could be the amount of javascript running on the page. Certain CSS can cause major animation problems; for example, I remember rewriting a page once because the way I was handling margins was causing severe calculation lag with the jQuery animations. I'd recommend just Googling "jQuery animation performance tips", and seeing if any apply to your HTML/CSS. Also see http://bluedesk.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-with-requestanimationframe.html

Comment: It looks like your html is nested fairly deeply. You have a lot of nested div elements. IE8 and 9 are no spring chickens now, and the more heavy your dom the more memory you page takes up, and the slower it will become. Especially once JavaScript animation is involved (that is fairly expensive already). Try to strip out some of the complexity of your html and make it lighter, and you should see a speedup.

Comment: Can you provide code, please? We shouldn't have to dig into your site to find it.

Comment: Every body should now start shifting to chrome or firefox or opera , IE dose not supports HTML 5

Comment: Looks like you have quite a considerable amount of html in nested divs. Also you are running loads of different javascripts on the page, some of which are not required for that page you have shown. I would suggest doing a tidy up of your HTML and then going through and only loading the javascripts you need to load on the page you use skrollr.